# In push notifications, images/videos are not showing when the application is running in the background or has been killed?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am developing an app in React native, want to show image/video in push notification when the app is in background or killed. When the app is in foreground it is doing fine but in background only title and message is showing but not the image/video. For push notification I am using **react-native-firebase and @notifee/react-native** to achieve this

```
export const notificationListener = async () => {
  messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  });
  async function onMessageReceived(message) {
    notifee.displayNotification({
      title: message.notification.title,
      body: message.notification.body,
      ios: {
        sound: 'default',
        attachments: [
          {
            url: message.data.video,
            thumbnailTime: 3,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  });
};
```